State/Province Tags
Should tags that are about a state/province include what country they are part of? As an example the iowa tag did not mention what country it is part of and people who do not know all the US states might not know it is part of the US.
I have suggested an edit for that tag to include the country in it.
As a side note should other area tags such as city include the state/country that they are part of to make it easier to understand the location in question when they are used in a question?

There's nothing wrong with adding more context to the tag descriptions. These are short descriptions that pop up when one hovers over the tag. I saw your minor suggested edit and voted to approve. It is now fully approved and live.
We can all improve tag descriptions as we see helpful.

This is what I am asking about, I think adding some additional information to these tags would help those who are not as knowledge about all parts of the world better understand the question.

yep, I wasn't suggesting that we do a site wide push rather something that we look at when approving edits for new or existing tags that could use it.

No
AFAIK, there is only one iowa, new-south-wales, and punjab. And, if I’m wrong, the likelihood that anyone would be talking about the other one is minuscule. Anyone that is confused by the sun-jurisdiction tag a) can Google it, and b) probably doesn’t know enough to give a good answer.
If the OP is worried about this, they have four other tags to put a country in.

Georgia on my mind...

I think you are misunderstanding what I am suggesting which is that in the case of Iowa that some might not know that Iowa is a part of the United States. I asked this question because I saw an answer on the main site that said they didn't mention the location even though it had the iowa tag on it. Not to mention there are plenty of cases where there are cities with the same name in the same country or in different contires.

There's only a single case where that could be relevant at all:
georgia is the name of a US state, a Country at the intersection of Europe and Asia, and an island in the atlantic (South Georgia Island) IF we ever need it, we'd make a georgia-country and south-georgia-island

The question is not about changing the tag - the question is about adding to the tag's description text.

@Jen And I said: there is only a single tag that arguably can point to multiple places at once - Georgia

I think you are misunderstanding what I am suggesting which is that in the case of Iowa that some might not know that Iowa is a part of the United States. I asked this question because I saw an answer on the main site that said they didn't mention the location even though it had the iowa tag on it. Not to mention there are plenty of cases where there are cities with the same name in the same country or in different contires

@JoeW I am not - that Iowa is either a US ship (and thus not relevant) or a US state should be common knowledge, no need for more. We don't tag cities ar all - We only tag jurisdictions, and the only jurisdicion that exists multiple times under the same name is Georgia: as a US state and a Country.

We have the [tag:new-york-state] and [tag:new-york-city] which means we have tags for cities even if you think we don't need them. The point I am trying to make is that while you might know that Iowa is part of the united states there are other cases around the world that if I saw the tag I would have no clue what country it was part of without googling it which is what I am trying to solve.
